# Headset input and output don't work at same time, sound setting sees 3 microphones when headset plugged in 20.04 Dell XPS 15

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

I have a set of Bose QuietComfort35 headphones that I am using with a cable in the audio jack on my XPS 15 because I was hoping to get around the issues with simultaneous input/output over bluetooth. Sound plays out of the headset, but when I switch the input to "Headset Audio," the sound through the headset stops.

Result of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` was ALC289.

More specifically what happens:

1. I plug in the headset
2. A menu pops up asking me to select "Headphones" "Headset" or "Microphone"
3. I select "Headset" (or any of the others, none fix the issue)
4. Sound comes through the headset, but the computer uses the built-in speakers.

At this point in the sound menu, I can see 3 microphones (not 2) in the "Input" menu: "Headset Microphone-Built in Audio", "Microphone-Built-in Audio", and "Internal Microphone-Built-in Audio". The Output dropdown contains "Headphones-Built-in Audio" and "Speakers-Built-in Audio"

Different things happen when I select different combinations of inputs/outputs:

- Output: Headphones + Input: Headset Microphone plays audio through the headset but doesn't take any sound input whatsoever
- Output: Headphones + Input: Internal Microphone plays audio through the headset and takes audio input through the internal microphone
- Output: Headphones + Input: Headset Microphone plays no audio whatsoever but takes audio input through the headset mic.

So, basically I can choose to either have my headset play or record, not both. And there's a mysterious third audio input detected ("Headset Microphone") that doesn't take any input.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @emcutty did you find a solution? I have the exact same setup and problem